# How to save an image in Laravel 10 API sent as base64?

Tags: file-upload, vuejs3, base64, laravel-10

I have a Vue 3 app that uploads an image as base64 to Laravel

```
  const uploadFile = async (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  if (!file) return; // Check if file is selected

  // Read file as base64
  const base64String = await readFileAsBase64(file);
  // Prepare file data
  const preparedFile = prepareFileForUpload(file, base64String);
  // Create FormData object
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('name', "anything");
  formData.append('file', preparedFile);

  // Send file to Laravel API
  const response = await Api().post('/app-upload', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  });

  // Handle response
  if (response.status === 200) {
    console.log('File uploaded successfully!');
    // Reset file input and other state
  } else {
    console.error('Error uploading file:', response.statusText);
  }
};

// Function to read file as base64
const readFileAsBase64 = async (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
};

// Function to prepare file for upload
const prepareFileForUpload = (file, base64String) => {
  const fileType = encodeURIComponent(file.type);
  return `data:${fileType};base64,${base64String}`;
};
```

Payload:

```
file: data:image%2Fjpeg;base64,data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk..........
```

In laravel 10 I save it like this

```
$base64Image = $request->input('file'); // Assuming 'image' is the parameter key
if (!is_string($base64Image) || empty($base64Image)) {
     return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid image data provided'], 400);
}
$imageData = base64_decode($base64Image);
$fileName = 'image_' . time() . '.jpg'; // Use extracted type for extension
try {
    file_put_contents(storage_path('app/public/uploads/' . $fileName), $imageData);
```

I also tried

```
$image = $request->file;  // your base64 encoded
$image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$imageName = time() . '.png';
Storage::disk('local')->put($imageName, base64_decode($image));
```

Image gets saved but it doesn't open. I tried multiple types of files all don't open (with changing the extension to the correct one for each file type). What's wrong with this code to save the file corrupted?